# how to set a water mark text box for inputing password in windows phone?

Tags: textbox, windows-phone-8, watermark

How to set a text box for inputing password in windows phoen ? Password box is not work for me because it not aalow watermark

I want something like

`<input type="password" />` in Android.

Comment: You can implement your own. [See this sample](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-watermarkedtextbox-custom-control)

Comment: @AlaaMasoud:Thanks for replay but just change charater style we have to develope another control its not good solution ...any other idea?

Comment: try with `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit` you have `PhoneTextBox` witch have property `Hint`

Comment: @radoslaf:thanks but it shows character when i insert password and i want show character=*

Answer (score 1):

I got solution from bellow link

[Windows Phone watermark on password box](http://damianblog.com/2011/01/21/wp7-password-watermark/)

Answer (score 0):

u can use PasswordBox control

http://www.bondigeek.com/blog/2010/03/29/windows-phone-7-dev-series-textbox-input-scope/

Comment: :thanks but password box control not allow watermark and i want both password character and watermark